# How can I apply multiple radial-gradient properties to a single element in CSS?

Tags: css, reactjs, gradient, linear-gradients, radial-gradients

## I have a problem in applying multiple gradient property in css.

I want to apply two radial-gradient properties into a <div> element.
This is what I did.

```html
`
...
<style>
.gradient-bg {
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 100% 15%, #1f3764 2%, #090915 10%), radial-gradient(circle at 0% 50%, red 2%, #090915 10%);
}
</style>

...
<div className="gradient-bg">
 <div>...</div>
</div>
}
...

`
```

I thought this would work, but only the first radial-gradient property was applied, and not the second one.

Comment: There's no transparency so only the first one (which takes precedence in background-image) can be seen. However, what do you want the result to look like? are the circles to have 'solid' edges or is there some blending to happen?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply multiple radial gradients to a class by setting the value of the gradients to `transparent` so that the other backgrounds are visible:

```
.gradient-bg {
  background: 
    radial-gradient(closest-corner at 50% -10%, 
            rgba(5, 5, 5, .7), 
            transparent), 
    radial-gradient(closest-corner at 50% 110%, 
            rgba(5, 5, 5, .7), 
            transparent);
}
```

See this post and article for extensive examples and details of applying multiple gradients.

[How to apply multiple css radial gradients to a single element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10677429/how-to-apply-multiple-css-radial-gradients-to-a-single-element)

https://css-tricks.com/radial-gradient-recipes/

Comment: Hi, Inosphere. Thank you for your answer.
I tried again, but still it is the same. :(
https://css-tricks.com/radial-gradient-recipes/
In the article above, scss is used.
I want to know if it's possible in css or not.
If you have experience in applying two gradients with css, please let me know, I'll appreciate.
Thank you.